# Order of unknowns in Prolog constraint logic programming (clpr)

Tags: prolog, clpr

I have:

```
:-use_module(library(clpr)).
comp(X, Y, Z):-
    {X = Y * Z, Y = Z, Y > 0, Z > 0}.
```

Which with the query:

```
?-comp(X,3,Z).
```

Yields:

```
X = 9.0,
Z = 3.0
```

as expected. But why doesn't

```
comp(9,Y,Z).
```

also give me values for Y and Z? What I get is instead:

```
{Z>0.0,Y=Z,9-Y*Z=0.0},
{9-Y*Z=0.0},
{9-Y*Z=0.0}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better with constraints over finite domains using [this](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html) module:

```
:-use_module(library(clpfd)).
comp(X, Y, Z):-
    X #= Y * Z, Y #= Z, Y #> 0, Z #> 0.
```

With

```
comp(9,Y,Z).
```

I get:

```
Y = Z, Z = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably a weakness of the used CLP(R) that quadratic case doesn't work so well. After Y = Z, it is evident that X = Y**2, and then with X = 9 and Y > 0, you should easily get Y = 3. Which CLP(R) do you use?

A CLP(R) need not only support linear equalities and inequalities. Using for example Gröbner Basis algorithm a CLP(R) could do more, even algebraically. Some computer algebra system can do that easily.

So I guess its not a problem of Prolog per se, rather of the library. Strictly speaking CLP(X) only indicates a domain X. For the domain R of real numbers there is wide variety of potential equation and inequation solvers.

Comment: jumping to X = Y**2 is easy for humans, but even X = Y*Y with a known X should conclude Y must be discoverable as well. How, is another issue. But it could be done even numerically...